# Regular expression in Telegram bot not working

Tags: python, regex, bots, telegram

I have spent three days trying to make my bot smarter, but I can't understand how to write a regular expression. I want search in the user's message and send an answer to it:

```
import re
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == re.search(r'hello','Hello'):
        bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome")
```

This isn't working, the bot just ignores my message.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `re.search(r'hello','Hello') is None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe checking `is None` is not python style. Simple `if re.search(...)` is sufficient.

Comment: @DmitryFrolov it is when you want to explicitly test for `None` (vs. for example `""`, which also evaluates false-y). Also I'm not suggesting it as a conditional, I'm trying to point out that such a function call **always** evaluates to `None` (which is probably `!= message.text`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first suggest you read the documentation for [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) - its use can be quite subtle at times.

I'll presume that what you're trying to do is run the function `if message.text == "Hello"`. With that, the snippet you're looking for is

```
if re.search(r'Hello|hello', message.text):
    #do things
```

Comment: Dammit, 30 seconds late!

Comment: You `if` is not in python syntax.

Comment: Hmm. Whilst I'll concede the parentheses are optional, I always worked under the impression that they weren't incorrect syntax?

Comment: @DmitryFrolov it's not the Python *convention* (per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), but it *is* still syntactically valid.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I know. But it is no OK to use such expressions.

Comment: @DmitryFrolov then by all means point out that it's not the *convention*, but don't try to claim it's not the *syntax*. Syntax is very important in programming, you need to be precise about these things.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not a programmer and need some help with my stupid mistakes. Thank you so much, and be happy in New Year. You are awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

You `if` and `re` expression is weird. What logic do you want to implement? If you want to check does `message.text` contain `hello` or `Hello` (exactly) you should use:

```
if re.search(r'hello|Hello', message.text):
```